# TypeScript - invoking React prop with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to convert my Jest tests using Enzyme to TypeScript, but running into one particular case that I'm not sure how to handle. Basically, I'm trying to call a function that is passed as a prop to a sub-component. The error I'm seeing is:

spec/javascript/_common/components/sidebar_spec.tsx:85:5 - error TS2349:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{}' has no compatible call signatures.

85     component.find(Link).at(0).prop('onNavigate')();
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How do I get past this error? Not sure if it's helpful, but more context for the test:

```
it('does not hide the sidebar after a link is clicked', () => {
  const component = shallow(<Sidebar />);

  component.find(Link).at(0).prop('onNavigate')();
  component.update();

  expect(component.find(Link)).toHaveLength(3);
});
```

And a chunk of code from the `Sidebar` component:

```
class Sidebar extends React.Component<any, any> {

  ...

  hideIfMobile() {
    const {mobile} = this.state;

    if (mobile) { this.setState({visible: false}); }
  }

  render() {
    const {visible} = this.state;

    if (!visible) {
      return (
        <div className='sidebar sidebar--hidden'>
          {this.sidebarToggle()}
        </div>
      );
    }

    const linkProps = {
      baseClass: 'sidebar__link',
      onNavigate: this.hideIfMobile,
    };

    return (
      <div className='sidebar sidebar--visible'>
        <h2 className='sidebar__header'>{'Menu'}{this.sidebarToggle()}</h2>
        <hr className='sidebar__divider' />
        <Link to='root' {...linkProps}><h2>{'FOCUS'}</h2></Link>
        <Link to='tasks' {...linkProps}><h2>{'ALL TASKS'}</h2></Link>
        <Link to='timeframes' {...linkProps}><h2>{'TIMEFRAMES'}</h2></Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

the Link component is wrapped in `react-redux`:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import Link from 'src/route/components/link';
import {getRouteName} from 'src/route/selectors';
import {setRoute} from 'src/route/action_creators';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {routeName: getRouteName(state)};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {setRoute})(Link);
```

and the actual component:

```
class Link extends React.Component<any, any> {
  navigate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const {onNavigate, params, setRoute, to} = this.props;

    setRoute({name: to, ...params});

    if (onNavigate) { onNavigate(); }
  }

  path() {
    const {params, to} = this.props;
    const pathParams = mapValues(params, value => value.toString());

    return findRoute(to).toPath(pathParams);
  }

  className() {
    const {baseClass, className, to, routeName} = this.props;

    return classnames(
      baseClass,
      {[`${baseClass}--active`]: baseClass && routeName === to},
      className,
    );
  }

  render() {
    const {children} = this.props;

    return (
      <a
        href={this.path()}
        className={this.className()}
        onClick={this.navigate}
      >
        {children}
      </a>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the definition of `Link` to the question.  When I define it as `class Link extends React.Component<{baseClass: string, onNavigate: () => void}, {}> {}`, I don't get the error.

Comment: Added. I'm using the `class` syntax in this case, too. However, it's also wrapped in a `react-redux` container.

Comment: Probably something is wrong with the inference of the props type of the component produced by your `connect` call.  To reproduce the problem, I'll need to know the types of `getRouteName` and `setRoute`.  Or you can investigate by yourself, starting by hovering over the `default` in `export default connect...` to see what the type is.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Not sure if `getRouteName` and `setRoute` are relevant in this case. When I remove them entirely I still see the same error. The return of the `connect` call when I remove the action creators and state is `(alias) connect(): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<DispatchProp<AnyAction>, {}> (+11 overloads)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `Link` in this case was defined earlier in my test file as:

```
const Link = 'Connect(Link)';
```

I switched this to import the actual link container and it resolved the issue.

```
import Link from 'src/route/containers/link';
```